# I have two microphones in my UWP app, how to give a drop down and select the microphone choosen

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have two microphones connected, I got how to show a drop down but , I do not know how to select the mic to be used in my app after the drop down is selected, like how we select in teams or skype.

Answer (score 1):

> how to give a drop down and select the microphone choosen

Please check [`AudioCreation`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation) code sample. Before create audio, it allow you select which device should be used.

```
private async Task PopulateDeviceList()
{
    outputDevicesListBox.Items.Clear();
    outputDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(MediaDevice.GetAudioRenderSelector());
    outputDevicesListBox.Items.Add("-- Pick output device --");
    foreach (var device in outputDevices)
    {
        outputDevicesListBox.Items.Add(device.Name);
    }
}
```

If you use `MediaCapture` class, you could also specific  [`MediaCaptureInitializationSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacaptureinitializationsettings) for the capture, and it contains `AudioDeviceId` that could specific which microphone should be used.

Comment: I am using speechrecogniser.

Comment: `SpeechRecognizer` class does not support specific microphone, it will chose the system audio input device. if you want to specific microphone device please modify the system setting.(setting->system->sound->input)

Comment: Is there any other way that I can convert Speech to text and also choose the mic?

Comment: You could edit the system default mic in system setting page.

Comment: That is not an option , the app will be in Kiosk mode

Comment: If you do want this feature, please feel free post your requirement with feedbackhub app.